# Doing an 'OrderByDescending' on each child List in a Parent List

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a parent list that contains multiple child lists of the same type and I need to process an `OrderByDescending` function on each of the lists in the parent list. I know it is confusing so here you go:

```
public class Message
{
    DateTime dateTime;
    int id;
}

List<Message> listOfMessages; //Contains a list of Messages
```

And there's another List named 'ConversationList' that contains multiple 'listOfMessages' lists.

Here's what I tried:

```
    var newList = listOfMessages.OrderByDescending(x => x.dateTime).ToList();
    //This would return a list of messages that are ordered by datetime
    //However listOfMessages is ONE item from ConversationList
    //Therefore I need to do OrderByDescending on each 'listOfMessages' in the ConversationList
```

**`listOfMessages` contains objects of type `Message` AND `ConversationList` contains multiple `listOfMessages`  LISTS.**

I need to `OrderByDescending` each list. Dang, what do yall suggest?

Comment: Have you tried: `ConversationList.Select(list => list.OrderByDescending(x => x.dateTime));`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You gave the answer yourself, you have to iterate through each list and order it

```
for(int i = 0; i <  ConversationList.Count; i++)
{
    var listOfMessages = ConversationList[i];
    ConversationList[i] = listOfMessages.OrderByDescending(x => x.dateTime).ToList();
}
```

With Linq, solution can look like below

```
ConversationList = ConversationList.Select(listOfMessages => listOfMessages.OrderByDescending(x => x.dateTime).ToList()).ToList();
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid loops mate